# How to creat function jquery to parse json

Tags: jquery, json

I want the PHP script to return the data in JSON format to the jquery

```
<?php
$json = array();
$json[] = array(
    'id'=>1,
    'username'=>'Administrator',
    'session'=>'251981564887'
);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Getting JSON object by calling PHP script

```
[
    {
        'id':1,
        'username':'Administrator',
        'session':'251981564887',
    }
]
```

Parse this JSON query using jQuery $.get()

```
$.get('json.php', function(json) {
    $data = json.replace('[', '');
    $data = $data.replace(']', '');
    $data = $.parseJSON($data);
    console.log('ID: '+$data.id);
    console.log('Username: '+$data.username);
    console.log('Session: '+$data.session);
});
```

Everything is fine...

How to creating custom function to parse JSON data (real simple)?

```
$.get('json.php', function(json) {
    $id = json.function_json('id');
    $username = json.function_json('username');
    $session = json.function_json('session');
    console.log('ID: '+$id);
    console.log('Username: '+$username);
    console.log('Session: '+$session);
});
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You want to parse JSON? `JSON.parse()` ? With JQuery `$.get('SomeURL',{'some objects':'some values'},function (callback),'json');`

Comment: i want function to parse json **json.function_json('username')**. The functions therein: **json** as _parse json data_, **'username'** as _key name_

Comment: Once the **WHOLE** data is parsed as a `JSON Object`, you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the `datatype` when you call your `$.get()` function so that **JQuery parses it for you** automagically ([source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)):

`jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] );`

Adapted example:

`$.get('json.php', function(json) { /* Your function */}, 'json');`

Default value:

> Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html).

Comment: I understand the problem. Thank you to everybody who helped

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can use `$.parseJSON`

```
var j = $.parseJSON(json);
```

then get value as `j.username` etc

Answer (score 1):

Use `getJSON()`, that way it is already decoded for you.

```
$.getJSON('json.php', function(json) {
    $.each(json[0], function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 - was just thinking this, why not use the function that is actually made for getting JSON ?

Comment: Have I finally found the solution to my problems (Jeff Noel)